# Google Drive doesn't work on OSX 10.11.1

Tags: google-drive, osx-el-capitan

My Google Drive app seems to have quit working. It always stated "prepare syncronisation" and never finished. So I uninstalled and reinstalled it. Now I can't even open the freshly downloaded app, as it gives me this error:

```
You are using an old version of Google Drive. Please use the latest one.
```

The Google Drive version I downloaded is 1.25. And it seems that I can't choose the version when downloading it from [the Drive homepage](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

The strange thing is that it worked perfectly fine until a few days. I made the update from 10.11 to 10.11.1 a few days ago and I think that the problems occurred since then.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and now it's working. Apparently OSX update breaks the Drive.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/tr_tUhfZmnw

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Link only answers aren't great because the link might break in the future. Can you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/992351/edit) your post to cover the main steps needed to solve the problem?